# Some Functions seems to be not exist when creating new bucket or checking if bucket exists using OpenBD

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, coldfusion, openbd

I am using OpenBD and trying to check whether bucket exists or not on my S3 server, if it is not exist then, to create new bucket. Here's my code:

index.cfm

```
<cfset request.awsaccess = "zzzzawsaccesszzzz">
<cfset request.awskey = "zzzzzzzzawskeyzzzzzzzz">
<cfset request.datasource="tcs">
<cfset request.region="us-west-2">
<cfscript>
    AmazonRegisterdatasource(datasource=request.datasource,awsaccess=request.awsaccess,awskey=request.awskey,region=request.region );
    result = AmazonS3listbuckets( datasource=request.datasource );
    WriteDump(result);
    WriteOutput(result.bucket[1]);
</cfscript>
```

For the above code I am getting this output:

[image: Result of above code]

Now I am adding one more function [AmazonS3createbucket()](http://openbd.org/manual/?/function/amazons3createbucket),

```
<cfscript>
    result = AmazonS3createbucket( datasource=request.datasource, bucket="anyBucket" );
</cfscript>
```

For the above script I am getting error: that `No such function exists - amazons3createbucket.`. Here's the screenshot:

[image: Result of AmazonS3bucketexists]

I am referring the [OpenBD Manual](http://openbd.org/manual/?/function/category/amazon) to filter these function. 
Also faced the same problem while using this functions also:

```
<cfscript>
    result = AmazonS3bucketexists( datasource=request.datasource, bucket="anyBucket" );
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using an alternate syntax?

```
<cfscript>
    result = AmazonS3bucketexists(ArgumentCollection = {
        datasource : request.datasource, 
        bucket : "anyBucket" 
        });
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Not me, I don't wanna waste my one reputation for down voting without comment. And yes, I tried this way also. No luck.